# Loading user settings from XML with settings.Object not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, configurationmanager

My WinForm program saves out an xml copy of user settings, the problem I'm having is loading it back in again.

I have copied this code from a blog: [Code Snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/24482/persisting-data-using-xml-config-files-in-winforms-saving-and-restoring-user-and-application-data/)

The error occuring happens where commented in the code below.

> Could not import settings. Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.

**[Update]** I have just noticed that it actually works when running the program from Visual Studio 2013, however does not when run from Windows File Explorer.

**[Update2]** I think because it is the first time I had run this from the desktop, I'm a different user and my user settings config file has not been created yet, this is the issue.

```
try{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

    // returns "[MyApplication].Properties.Settings";
    string appSettingsXmlName = Properties.Settings.Default.Context["GroupName"].ToString();
    // Open settings file as XML
    var import = XDocument.Load(filename);
    // Get the whole XML inside the settings node
    var settings = import.XPathSelectElements("//" + appSettingsXmlName);

    //***Error occurs in the following code***
    config.GetSectionGroup("userSettings")
        .Sections[appSettingsXmlName]
        .SectionInformation
        .SetRawXml(settings.Single().ToString());

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("userSettings");

    appSettings.Reload();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not import settings. " + ex.Message);
}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DropLib.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <DropLib.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ORG_SETTINGS" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <string>ORG1-||-server1-||-Proj 94-||-email@ORG1.com-|||-Server-|-Server-|-Folder$-|-http://server1/proj-|-c:\inetpub\wwwroot\proj\</string>
                        <string>ORG2-||-server2-||-Proj 94-||-email@ORG2.com-|||-Server-|-Server-|-Folder$-|-http://server2/proj-|-c:\inetpub\wwwroot\proj\</string>
                    </ArrayOfString>
                </value>
            </setting>
        </DropLib.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are a different user depending if you run from VS or from the desktop.

When I ran the program from the desktop for the first time, a user.config file had not been created yet.

Solution: Added a check to see if the user.config had been created, if not perform a save of the user settings, which will create it.

New Code:

```
try
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    //Check user.config exists
    if (!File.Exists(config.FilePath))
    {
        [EDIT]
        DropLib.Properties.Settings.Default.MY_SETTING = "";
        [/EDIT]
        DropLib.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    }

    // returns "[MyApplication].Properties.Settings";
    string appSettingsXmlName = Properties.Settings.Default.Context["GroupName"].ToString();

    // Open settings file as XML
    var import = XDocument.Load(filename);

    // Get the whole XML inside the settings node
    var settings = import.XPathSelectElements("//" + appSettingsXmlName);

    config.GetSectionGroup("userSettings")
        .Sections[appSettingsXmlName]
        .SectionInformation
        .SetRawXml(settings.Single().ToString());

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("userSettings");

    appSettings.Reload();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not import settings. " + ex.Message);
    appSettings.Reload(); // from last set saved, not defaults
}
```

Comment: I have altered this solution a little, it seems you have to at least initialize one of the settings before the save works.